# Function releases after page is loaded not after click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a game of little rabbit's farm. My level of programming is a beginner.

1. Why is addRabbit() code starts to work after the page is loaded? I wrote it to work after click to "Buy Rabbit" button
2. Why rabbits are not shown at the page near the "Sell Rabbit" and "Buy Rabbit" buttons?
3. I know that I have a lot of issues here as far as I'm a beginner. Could I ask you to mention any of them?

```js
// VARIABLES
// variables for modal of chosing rabbits
const chooseModal = document.querySelector(".choose-modal");
const selectRabbitBtn = document.querySelector(".choose-rabbit-btn");
const rabbitSelects = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");
let chosenRabbitUrl = "img/rabbit1.png";
// start screen
const startScreenDiv = document.querySelector(".story-modal");
const rabbit = document.querySelector("img.rabbit");
const buyRabbitBtn = document.querySelector(".buy-btn");



// EVENT LISTENERS
selectRabbitBtn.addEventListener("click", chooseTheRabbit);

// FUNCTIONS

function chooseTheRabbit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    for (let rabbit of rabbitSelects) {
        if (rabbit.checked) {
            chosenRabbitUrl = `img/${rabbit.id}.png`;
            break;
        }
    }
    chooseModal.style.display = "none";
    startScreen();
}

function startScreen() {
    startScreenDiv.style.display = "block";
    rabbit.src = chosenRabbitUrl;
}

class RabbitGame {
    constructor() {
        this.rabbitsCount = parseInt(document.querySelector(".rabbits-count").innerText, 10);
        this.rabbitsCountSpan = document.querySelector(".rabbits-count");
        this.rabbitsShowDiv = document.querySelector(".rabbits-count-show");
        this.coinsCount = parseInt(document.querySelector(".coins-count").innerText, 10);
        this.coinsCountSpan = document.querySelector(".coins-count");
        this.sellRabbitBtn = document.querySelector(".sell-btn");
        this.myRabbits = [{age: 0, src: chosenRabbitUrl, width: 50}];
    };

    // function, that shows rabbits on the page, that the owner have
    // adult rabbits should be bigger, little rabbits smaller
    showRabbits() {
        // rabbit.src = chosenRabbitUrl
        this.myRabbits.forEach((rabbit) => {
        this.rabbitsShowDiv.innerHTML += `<img src="${rabbit.src}" width="${rabbit.width}">`});
    };

    // function that adds a rabbit, if the owner doesn't have any coin, rabbits eat him
    addRabbit() {
        console.log("Hello");
        if (this.coinsCount > 1) {
            // remove 1 coin
            this.coinsCount -= 1
            console.log(this.coinsCount);

            // show 1 coin less
            this.coinsCountSpan.innerText = this.coinsCount

            // add 1 for rabbits age
            // if the rabbit is older than 4, make him bigger on screen
            this.myRabbits.forEach((rabbit) => {
                rabbit.age +=1;
                if (rabbit.age > 3) {
                    rabbit.width = 70
                }
            })
            // add 1 more rabbit to array
            this.myRabbits.push({age: 0, src: chosenRabbitUrl, width: 50});

            // show 1 more rabbit
            this.rabbitsShowDiv.innerHTML += `<img src="${rabbit.src}" width="${rabbit.width}">`
        }
    };


    // функция, которая продает кролика, если он взрослый
    // если нет взрослых кроликов, выводит предупреждение, что нет взрослых кроликов
}

const rabbitGame = new RabbitGame();
rabbitGame.showRabbits;
buyRabbitBtn.addEventListener("click", rabbitGame.addRabbit());
```

```css
/* GENERAL */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h3 {
  background-color: rgb(108, 165, 55);
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-color: rgb(194, 89, 89);
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(172, 79, 84);
}

/* END OF GENERAL */

/* CHOOSE RABBIT MODAL & RULES MODAL */
.choose-modal,
.rules-modal {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.choose-modal > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
}

label > img:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(199, 199, 199);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.button-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* END OF CHOOSE RABBIT MODAL & RULES MODAL */

/* START SCREEN */
/* .story-modal {
  display: none;
} */

.story-modal {
  background-image: url("img/neighbour.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

img.rabbit {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40%;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.story-modal > h3 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 5%;
}

.img-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.3);
}

.story-modal > button {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 13%;
}

/* END OF START SCREEN */

/* MAIN GAME */
.main-game {
  display: flex;
}
/* END OF MAIN GAME */
```

```html
    <div class="choose-modal">
        <div>
        <div class="choose-modal-header">
            <h3>Please, choose the rabbit</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="rabbit1"><input type="radio" id="rabbit1" name="rabbits" value="rabbit1"><img src="img/rabbit1.png" width="100" alt="rabbit1"></label>
            <label for="rabbit2"><input type="radio" id="rabbit2" name="rabbits" value="rabbit2"><img src="img/rabbit2.png" width="100" alt="rabbit2"></label>
            <label for="rabbit3"><input type="radio" id="rabbit3" name="rabbits" value="rabbit3"><img src="img/rabbit3.png" width="80" alt="rabbit3"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="button-div">
            <button type="submit" value="Choose" class="choose-rabbit-btn">Choose</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="story-modal">
        <div class="img-overlay"></div>
        <h3>Your pretty neighbour gave you a rabbit</h3>
        <img alt="rabbit" src="#" class="rabbit">
        <button>Rules</button>
    </div>
    <div class="rules-modal">
        <div>
        <h3>Rules of game</h3>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Buy grass to feed the rabbits</li>
                <li>Sell adult rabbits</li>
                <li>Buy new little rabbits</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="button-div">
            <button>Play</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="main-game">
        <div class=" navbar">
            <p><img src="img/coin.png" height="20"> Coins <span class="coins-count">10</span></p>
            <p class="name-of-gamer">Anonymous</p>
            <p><img src="img/rabbit.png" height="20"> Rabbits <span class="rabbits-count">3</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="rabbits-count-show"></div>
        <div>
            <button class="sell-btn">Sell Rabbit</button>
            <button class="buy-btn">Buy Rabbit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: 1) Because you're invoking the function (and passing its return value) to the event handler, not passing a **reference** to the function. Should be: `buyRabbitBtn.addEventListener("click", () => rabbitGame.addRabbit());`

Comment: I updated my answer answering your second problem. sorry I diidn't saw it the first time. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the line

```
buyRabbitBtn.addEventListener("click", rabbitGame.addRabbit());
```

to

```
buyRabbitBtn.addEventListener("click", rabbitGame.addRabbit);
```

(simply removing those parenthesis) should work. When you add the parenthesis, a function gets called, and that's not what you want. When the button is clicked the eventlistener call the your function itself. as of your second problem you have to add parenthesis to the function to get called thus executing the code inside it.

NOTE: Do not post unnecessary files to a question. Try find the location that error could possibly occur. BTW, CSS has no contributing factor to a error in js code. sometimes html does. I know as a beginner it's hard to find the areas causing the error but it gets easier over time.